# Form W8BEN-E type of beneficial owner

Tags: taxes, corporation, uae

I just opened a FZE in UAE.
An FZE is technically a LLC with a single shareholder, who owns 100% of shares, and who is also self-employed with a defined salary and a payroll.

I'm filling out form W8BEN-E, and there's no option to select LLC.

An FZE is technically a mix of corporate and sole proprietorship but it's unclear what I should select from the available options (even to the FreeZone expert with whom I opened the company in Dubai).

Does anyone know what could be more suitable for this kind of company?

Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine how your entity is being treated under the UAE law. If it is a disregarded entity for tax purposes (i.e.: the entity doesn't pay taxes on its income and instead passes all the income/gain/loss recognition to the shareholders) - then select "Disregarded entity". Otherwise select "Corporation".

Comment: Thank you for your message. A little hard to understand given that Corporates don't pay taxes in UAE and I didn't have to select any taxation type when I incorporated it.
Anyway thank you, I believe for now I select Corporation. Thank you!